# Name that ...Name? 2

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I acted before retirement in 1986

My Norwegian ancestry is in no need of a fix

The actress I'm controlled by now loves getting things off her chest

But because of her my reputation isn't really the best

What is this name

Hint 1

> The last two lines of the actual rhyme are referring to a movie character played by an actress. This is the big reason why the name became popular in the USA in 2014 despite being popular in other parts of the world beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> **Elsa**

---

I acted before retirement in 1986

> Actress Elsa Lancaster died in 1986. She was nominated for 2 Oscars. Her last movie was in 1980 though, so I'm not entirely sure.

My Norwegian ancestry is in no need of a fix

> "Else" is a more common version of the name Elsa in Norway. In English however, you don't need to change it to something *Else* (i.e. you don't need to fix it).

The actress I'm controlled by now loves getting things off her chest

> Elsa is the <s>Princess</s> Queen in the Disney movie Frozen. The theme song, performed by the actress Idina Menzel is "Let it Go". To let go is the same as getting something off your chest.

But because of her my reputation isn't really the best

> From OP: *The last clue references how the name Elsa was of high nobility before Frozen came out. However, many people like Frozen and many people hate it, so the name isn't as recognized as noble. Because of this, the noble reputation isn't the best anymore.*